# Content editable UIWebView becomes lazy until not responding

Tags: ios, uiwebview, usability, contenteditable

After a few minutes of typing text in a content-editable UIWebView on a 3rd-generation iPad (wifi/AT&T cellular), the keyboards reacts slower and slower until application is not usable anymore. (tested under iOS 5.x and iOS6). This bug has been submitted to Apple, and I got no news. Here is the problem.

In a Content-editable UiWebView, user starts to type on the keyboard. You can either type for 2 to 10 minutes, or type some text and then pause typing while application is still foreground

After some delay, the keyboard reacting time becomes slower and slower, until one gets no reaction at all. Application is not crashed (adding a breakpoint makes the app pause), but it becomes impossible to type text, and there is no other solution than force-quit and reload application.

1. This problem does not arise on the iOS 6 simulator. The iPad (3rd gen) was bought earlier this year in France, with 64GB Wifi and Cellular/AT&T
2. This problem also arises in iOS 5.
3. My app creates a NSTimer that is fired every 0.8 second to call a scroll: method that is dedicated to vertical scrolling (if necessary). Reducing the NSTimer firing delay accelerates the arousal of the problem.

When disabling the scroll:method, the problem do not occurs. It seems that the javascript called in a UIWebView creates processes that are never stopped, so that it takes more and more CPU time, so that the app eventually becomes unresponsive (see point 5).

1. Using Time profiling with Instruments application, I noticed that when the application is functioning normally, it is the [WebFrame(WebInternal) stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFrom String:forceUserGesture] function that is the main time consuming method (about 6 to 8 ms for every call of the scroll: method. But when the application reactivity starts to decrease, three methods tend to dominate the time profile, the consumed time continue to increase fastly, and the time profiler graphic shows a full time activity while no key is pressed on the iPad. The methods are given here with the associated figures:

[WebVisiblePosition withinTextUnitOfGranularity:inDirectionIfAtBoundary]
(40% of total running time, after a 10 minutes of user inactivity)

[WebHTMLView(WebNSTextInputSUpport) insertText:]
(29% of total running time, after a 10 minutes of user inactivity)

[WebVisiblePosition enclosingTextUnitOfGranularity:inDirectionIfAtBoundary]
(16% of total running time, after a 10 minutes of user inactivity)

Did anybody had to deal with such issue. Can a turnaround be designed for that issue?